# XPath query node based on another node attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML

```
<NETCASTING>
    <MATCHINFO>
        <TEAM Name="TEAM A" >
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1987.04.20" Height="1.98" Surname="Robinson" Number="4"/>
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1988.07.11" Height="1.84" Surname="Zhedik" Number="7"/>
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1986.01.27" Height="1.86" Surname="Kirillova" Number="9"/>
        </TEAM>
        <TEAM Name="TEAM B" >
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1986.12.28" Height="1.97" Surname="Lyttle" Number="2"/>
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1989.09.18" Height="1.94" Surname="Arteshina" Number="4"/>
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1987.05.11" Height="1.96" Surname="Belyakova" Number="5"/>
            <PLAYER Birth_date="1989.03.13" Height="1.99" Surname="Baric" Number="9"/>
        </TEAM>
    </MATCHINFO>
    <BOXSCORE>
        <TEAM>
            <PLAYER Number="4" Start="1" Points="11"/>
            <PLAYER Number="7" Start="0" Points="3"/>
            <PLAYER Number="9" Start="1" Points="0"/>
        </TEAM>
        <TEAM>
            <PLAYER Number="2" Start="0" Points="14"/>
            <PLAYER Number="4" Start="0" Points="2"/>
            <PLAYER Number="5" Start="1" Points="2"/>
            <PLAYER Number="9" Start="0" Points="0"/>
        </TEAM>
    </BOXSCORE>
</NETCASTING>
```

I need to get the Surname, Birth_date, Height, Number & Points of every player in 1st Team (/TEAM[1]) where the Start="1"

So I need to get:

```
<PLAYER Birth_date="1987.04.20" Height="1.98" Surname="Robinson" Number="4" Points="11"/>
<PLAYER Birth_date="1986.01.27" Height="1.86" Surname="Kirillova" Number="9" Points="0"/>
```

of for 2nd TEAM (/TEAM[2])

```
<PLAYER Birth_date="1987.05.11" Height="1.96" Surname="Belyakova" Number="5" Points="2"/>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done using single XPath expression. Assuming that a match info is always consists of 2 opposing teams, then you can use 2 XPath queries, one for each team, and join the result using union (`|`) operator :

```
/NETCASTING/MATCHINFO/TEAM[1]/PLAYER[
    @Number = /NETCASTING/BOXSCORE/TEAM[1]/PLAYER[@Start=1]/@Number
] |
/NETCASTING/MATCHINFO/TEAM[2]/PLAYER[
    @Number = /NETCASTING/BOXSCORE/TEAM[2]/PLAYER[@Start=1]/@Number
]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/v7g3VV7YJ)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<PLAYER Birth_date="1987.04.20"
        Height="1.98"
        Surname="Robinson"
        Number="4"/>
<PLAYER Birth_date="1986.01.27"
        Height="1.86"
        Surname="Kirillova"
        Number="9"/>
<PLAYER Birth_date="1987.05.11"
        Height="1.96"
        Surname="Belyakova"
        Number="5"/>
```

Comment: Noble try, but it is actually impossible to meet OP's request with XPath alone given that no `PLAYER` element exists with the requested `@Points` attribute and the other requested attributes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

**XPath is for selection**, not for transformation.  (XSLT is for transformation.)

You can select only among `PLAYER` elements that exist in the input document.  Since there are no `PLAYER` elements in the input XML with `@Points` attributes ***and*** the other attributes (`@Birth_date` etc), your request, including,

```
<PLAYER Birth_date="1987.04.20" 
        Height="1.98" 
        Surname="Robinson" 
        Number="4"
        Points="11"/>  <!-- Cannot add Points attribute -->
```

is impossible to do with XPath alone.  You'll need help from the hosting language (XSLT, Python, Java, etc).